# ASP MVC radio button validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Im new to mvc and have several questions about asp mvc 3 validation, help regarding any of those would be apreciated:

First I have a model class that requires some fields to be present like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
public UInt16 SomeField { get; set; }
```

It's working but the error message is apearing in black font (i want it red), and i think that the validation is taking plance on the server side instead of on the client, i've been reading some tutorials about how to make javascript validation work but it's not working apparently:

Web.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEneabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Index.cshtml

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
```

That would be my second question, make it work on the client side.

And for some fields that have the `Required` validator and have a set of radio buttons asociated with them like this

model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
public UInt16 SomeField { get; set; }
```

view

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SomeField, 1) Label
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SomeField, 2) Label
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SomeField)
```

the validation message is not showing up (even on black font) when you miss to click a radio button, how you can make it show when there are not pressed buttons.

ASP MVC 3
Razor engine

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Microsoft*.js` scripts are deprecated in ASP.NET MVC 3 and should no longer be used. You can completely get rid of them. They are provided only for backwards compatibility if you are upgrading an older application. The same stands true for the `Html.EnableClientValidation();` helper. They were replaced by `jquery.validate` plugin and the unobtrusive validation scripts.

And since you have enabled unobtrusive validation in your web.config all you need in order to enable client side validation in an MVC 3 application is to include the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts, along with the version of `jquery` that you are using of course because both those scripts depend on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
```

Another remark about your code is the `[Required]` attribute that you applied to a non-nullable type (`ushort`). This makes no sense because non-nullable types, by their very nature, always have value. The Required attribute should be used only on nullable types, for example:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
public ushort? SomeField { get; set; }
```

As far as the color of the validation message is concerned, both client side and server side validation uses the same HTML structure. So it's really a matter of CSS to design the look and feel of those messages.

Comment: Does the regular jquery library need to be placed before or is it included already inside any of those.

Comment: Yes, before them, since they both depend on it.

Comment: I thought that MicrosoftAjax would take care of the error message's corresponding css, that means more work for me. +1

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Required attribute on a non-nullable type.  I catch that so many times when reviewing other peoples code when they ask "Why isn't this validating when I don't select anything?"

Comment: So how do you flag a property invalid when it still has the default value. loki obviously doesn't consider 0 valid. You told them why it doesn't work but now how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Declare model like this.. use Nullable<>

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
public  Nullable<UInt16> SomeField { get; set; }
```

and so when u submit the form without checking any radio button null value is come after this write this code

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View();
}
```

If u do not select any radio button then it return to your view and validation message is display...